# submit button won't work in div (contents of which are loaded using .load() in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[cart.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEe0F.png) [items.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z2cr.png)The following code displays products in the cart of a user.using the submit buttons user can delete individual items in the cart.It is saved in cart.php file.This code works fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart</div>
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>

</tr>   
 <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart where ip='".$ip."'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $item_total =0;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?><form method="post" action="" id="cart1">
        <tr> 
        <td><strong><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["qty"]; ?></td>
        <td align=right><?php echo "Rs.".$row["price"]; ?></td>
  <input name="no" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["orderno"] ?>" />   
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/></td>
  </tr>
    </form>

                <?php
       $item_total += ($row["price"]*$row["qty"]);
        }
 } 







 ?> 
 <?php if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $or=$_POST['no'];
     $sql = "delete FROM cart where orderno='".$or."'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);}
    ?>

<tr>

<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo     "Rs.".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>        

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when i load this into a div of another page items.php 
using

```html
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#cart").load('cart.php')
}, 20);
});

</script>
```

The cart.php is properly loading in the div #cart, but when i click on      submit nothing happens. Please note that on clicking submit in cart.php the product was deleted from the database.

Can anybody please explain how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the click handler is getting attached but the DOM(the submit button in your case) is not present , so you may need to `delegate` the `click` event like this

```
$('body').on('click','#submit',function(event){ // submit is id of submit button
  // rest of the code
})
```

Comment: $('#cart').on('click','#submit',function(event){ 
 alert("hello");
});   using this i was able to click on the submit button and display hello. But the event does not perform the same action it performed in cart.php,  i.e delete  the item from database. can u suggest on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem. Don't know if this is the "correct" way to do tis but it worked for me. I am posting the code here so that it may be of some use to others facing similar problem

in cart.php

```html
<form method="post" action="cart.php" id="cart1">
  <tr> 
   <td><strong><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></strong></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["qty"]; ?></td>
   <td align=right><?php echo "Rs.".$row["price"]; ?></td>
   <td><input  type="submit" name="<?php echo $row["orderno"] ?>" id="submit" value="Remove"/></td>
   </tr>
    </form>
```

The script was modified as

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#cart").load('cart.php')
}, 200);
});
        
        
        $('#cart').on('click','#submit',function(event){ 
          var no = $(this).attr('name');
            var b = parseInt(no);
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dlt.php',
        data: {no: b},
            });
               
});
        
        
</script>
```

and dlt.php is

```html
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
        

    $or=$_POST['no'];
     $sql = "delete FROM cart where orderno='".$or."'";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  
   
?>
```